# Rxjava Interval with ZipWith doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

```
compositeDisposable += Observable.zip(
            someObservable(),
            someObservableTwo(), { t1, t2 ->
                Pair(first, second)
            }
        ).zipWith(Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), { t1, t2 ->
            t1
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                //success
            }, {
                //error
            })
```

The main objective of this code to execute every 10 seconds. Logic is not wrong but somehow I am missing something. Hope someone helps

Comment: Your source Observable#zip most likely does not emit any value or at least it does not emit values in the same freq. as Observable#interval does. Observable#zip needs two values from both streams for each tuple. If one observable fires and another does not you will not get an invocation on your BiFunction mapper. Most of the time #zip is not the right tool and you should look into CombineLatest or WithLatestFrom. Could you please get into detail, what you are actually trying to achieve and what the problem is (e.g. no emits in subscribe?)

Comment: I idea is to call these two observables every 10 secs. the someObservable() and someObservable2() are two network apis.

Comment: I think you are write, I am using the wrong combination. CombineLatest will do what I need. it explains in theory. I have to see in code if it works, thanks for the hint. CombineLatest doc help with your hint `CombineLatest emits an item whenever any of the source Observables emits an item (so long as each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item)`

Answer (score 0):

What about following solution?

The source observable will emit an event ever 1_000ms. On each event both API endpoints will be called. When the interval source observable emits a new value, while the Observable#combineLatest is subscribed, it will be unsubscribed and called again (switchMap). If you do not want to cancel out the inner stream on each new emit, you woul use flatMap (NOTE: at max 128 concurrent streams are merged by flatMap by default)

```
interface Api {
    Observable<Integer> call1();

    Observable<String> call2();
}

static final class ApiImpl implements Api {

    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> call1() {
        return Observable.just(42);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<String> call2() {
        return Observable.just("42");
    }
}

@Test
public void interval() {
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    Api api = new ApiImpl();

    TestObserver<Integer> test = Observable.interval(0, 1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, testScheduler)
            .switchMap(aLong -> Observable.combineLatest(api.call1(), api.call2(), (integer, s) -> 42))
            .test();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    test.assertNotComplete().assertValueCount(1)
            .assertValues(42);

    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    test.assertNotComplete().assertValueCount(3)
            .assertValues(42, 42, 42);
}
```